# How to create workspace with no mappings using tf command?

Tags: visual-studio, cmd, tfvc

I'm trying to create a workspace with the `tf` command. I'd like to add the folder mappings later, but I don't see any [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/y901w7se(v=vs.100)) to instruct `tf` to create the workspace with no mappings. This is what I have:

```
tf workspace /server:<server> /new /noprompt MY_WORKSPACE
```

The above command-line creates the workspace with one active mapping, if I run:

```
tf workspaces /format:detailed /collection:<collection>
```

I get:

```
Workspace  : MY_WORKSPACE
Owner      : <ME>
Computer   : <My PC>
Comment    :
Collection : <collection>
Permissions: Private
Location   : Server
File Time  : Current

Working folders:
 $/: <Current directory where I run tf command>
```

If I do it from within visual studio (Enterprise 2017 v15.9.23),  I can effectively create a new workspace with no mappings. So, is there a "hidden" option to `tf workspace /new` that does what I want?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are no any options in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/y901w7se(v=vs.100)) to instruct `tf` to create the workspace with no mappings. But you could change the folder mappings later by [editing a Workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/y901w7se(v=vs.100)#editing-a-workspace).